# Co-occurrence matrix creation with cuda

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, cuda, gpu

```
//This is my kernel function

__global__ void createSCM(Pixel*pixelMat, //image
                          int imgRows, //image dimensions
                          int imgCols,
                          int*matrizSCM, //Coocurrence matrix
                          int numNiveles, //coocurrence matrix levels = 256
                          int delta_R, //value = {-1,0 or 1}
                          int delta_C) //value = {-1,0 or 1}
{
    int i = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int j = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

    int cols = numNiveles;

    int posx,posy;

    if ( (j + delta_C) < imgCols && (i + delta_R) < imgRows && 
       ((j + delta_C) >= 0) && ((i + delta_R) >= 0) )
    {
       posx = pixelMat[i*imgCols+j].channel_0;
       posy = pixelMat[(i + delta_R)*imgCols+(j + delta_C)].channel_0;

       matrizSCM[posx*cols+posy]++;
       matrizSCM[posy*cols+posx]++;
    }

}

struct Pixel {

    int channel_0;
};
```

I have counting errors in the coocurrence matrix, because

`pixelMat[i*imgCols+j]` and `pixelMat[(i + delta_R)*imgCols+(j + delta_C)]`

are accessing to different positions with the same thread.

This is my kernel call

```
int Grid_Dim_x=imagenTest.rows, Grid_Dim_y=imagenTest.cols;
int Block_Dim_x=1, Block_Dim_y=1;   

dim3 Grid(Grid_Dim_x, Grid_Dim_y);  
dim3 Block(Block_Dim_x,Block_Dim_x);

createSCM<<<Grid,Block>>>(...)
```

There is just one thread on each block, and each block represents a pixel

is there a nice solution to this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Only one thread per block?  Seems quite limiting. May want to think about your algorithm some more.  I'm not sure I'm following what you think the problem is exactly (instead of different positions with same thread, I would think *same position with different threads*), but it does seem to me that any thread can access an arbitrary position within matrizSCM so you might want to change your `matrizSCM[...]++;` lines to be atomic updates, i.e. [atomicAdd() or atomicInc()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Reading from different memory cells of immutable input incurs no parallel hazard that you would have to deal with. The problem lies within the `matrizSCM` where the same memory cell can be incremented by multiple threads at once.

An `atomicAdd(addr,1)` is a quick fix --- it should make the algorithm correct, but it may be fairly slow. Making it correct should be the first step; then you can look on available examples on the web of histogram computation and parallel reduction algorithm and check if it can be applied to your problem.

Finally, as Robert pointed out in the comment, launching just one thread in a block is very inefficient. You need a multiple of 32 to utilize the hardware SIMD unit, and usually about 256 threads to hide various memory latencies.

Also, if your image is big and you still need thousands of 256-thread blocks, you may consider launching less blocks (around 60-120) but having each block process multiple pixels sequentially. If you do that, you might be able to put a copy of `matrixSCM` in shared memory. This will make a separate copy of `matrixSCM` for each block, resulting in less atomic conflicts between the blocks. Obviously, at the end of the kernel, your block will still need to "submit" the partial result into the global one, but that would be a single step operation.